# How to convert all pandas timestamp timezones in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Imagine you had a dataframe like this, with multiple datetime columns in UTC. What is the best way to convert them all to a timezone of your choice, such as EST?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 12394, 1: 12393, 2: 12392, 3: 12391, 4: 12390},
 'created_timestamp': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:13:19.921394'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:10:36.176147'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:05:56.261883'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:02:06.483371'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:01:10.212199')},
 'City': {0: 'Boston',
  1: 'New York',
  2: 'Albany',
  3: 'Buffalo',
  4: 'Detroit'},
 'updated_timestamp': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:13:19.921394'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:10:36.176147'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:05:56.261883'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:02:06.483371'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2020-12-30 02:01:10.212199')}})
```

This is what I've tried:

```
timecols=df.select_dtypes(include=["datetime64[ns]"])

for col in timecols:
    df[col]=df[col] \
              .dt.tz_localize("UTC") \
              .dt.tz_convert("EST")
```

Is there a cleaner, more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: don't use `EST`, it's just in the database for historical reasons ([src](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/846c3ac7abc246094dd754ac6dc90423148a5107/northamerica#L188)). it will also give you a static tz, which is not what you want I'd assume. For US Eastern time zone, use e.g. `America/New_York`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=["datetime64[ns]"]).apply(lambda x: x.dt.tz_localize("UTC").dt.tz_convert("US/Eastern"))
```

Comment: @MrFuppes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

another option: make a boolean mask based on dtype, and use it in `loc`:

```
m = df.dtypes == 'datetime64[ns]'
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].apply(lambda x: x.dt.tz_localize("UTC").dt.tz_convert("America/New_York"))

df
      id  ...                updated_timestamp
0  12394  ... 2020-12-29 21:13:19.921394-05:00
1  12393  ... 2020-12-29 21:10:36.176147-05:00
...
```